# Ease in ease out on background image hover

Tags: html, css, hover, background-image, transition

I'm having issues getting a background image hover ease in and out effect on the bordered link and to be honest I don't even know which one to use. The image either moves with transition or it does nothing at all. Any help would be great. Thanks!

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGewxE

```
.cta { margin: 0; padding: 1.4em 0 1.4em 0; cursor:pointer; display:block; text-align:center; width:100%; font-size:  2.3em !important; color:#FFF !important; font-weight: 700; font-style: italic; text-transform: uppercase; border: 0; background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/BaLv0X5.jpg);  background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center center;}
.cta:hover { text-decoration:none; border: 0; opacity:0.8; }
a.cta  {border-bottom: none !important; text-decoration: none;}
.cta span {border: #fff 3px solid; padding: 0.3em;}
.cta span:hover {background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/mrbBt4f.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center center; }

<a class="cta" href="learn-more" title="Understand your data today!">
<p><span>Understand your data today!</span></p>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Transitions don't work with background-images unfortunately.  You can check the css specs - you can do background colors but not images.  You'll have to try a solution using images and jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I guess CSS transitions would work.

Add following CSS code to your classes **.cta** & **.cta span**

**CSS**

```
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; 
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
```

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNvxKm)

Comment: is this what is wanted?  thought they want to just change the image with the transition, not animated position?

Comment: @MiaSno, i think so because question itself says "ease in ease out on background image hover". Still lets see, if Compton finds it helpful or not.

Comment: @Compton, is this helpful?

Comment: I've already attempted the above and it's not what I'm looking for. Like MiaSno says, I would like to change the image with transition on hover.

Comment: ok so you want change at that particular rectangular box or at the whole page?

Comment: @divy3993 Yes, I would like change to just happen within the box.

Comment: @Compton some thing like [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNvxKm) or like [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXZmOG)?

Comment: @divy3993 Thanks, but no. This effect is the same as your demo but with a different image on hover, which isn't what I'm looking for. I would like the unblurred image to appear on hover with a fade basically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79688/discussion-between-divy3993-and-compton).

Answer (score 0):

@mia-sno is correct, you cannot transition background-images.  If you want to make the image change on hover consistently I would change:

```
.cta span:hover
```

to

```
.cta:hover span
```

Since there aren't any transitions in your codepen I would take @divy3993 advice and use that css.  And if you wanted to transition the image from blurred to focused you would need to restructure your html and get the image out of the background.  There's a few ways to do that but I hope that helps.